# PHPUnit and ZF1 - get errors in CLI

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit

I'm working on very first set of unit tests for Zend Framework 1.12 controller. In one of test cases I have the following lines:

```
  $this->assertController('student-professor');
  $this->assertResponseCode(200);
```

that produces error:

```
 Failed asserting last controller used <""> was "student-professor"
```

As I understand something went wrong and there was redirection to error(?) controller probably. Anyway I would like to get more information about errors or exceptions.

In the bootstrap I added lines to output all errors and redirect error messages to stdout, because I'm running tests from CLI

```
$cur_error_log = ini_get( 'error_log' );
ini_set( 'error_log', '/dev/stdout' );
error_log( 'This is a message from error_log()' );

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); // or error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
```

However, I still don't receive any error messages. What can be the cause of this failed asserting and how to get more detailed info about it?

Answer (score 1):

you can see in https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/blob/c57660e57755ec9920ac90d0e1cad5b6dc7fcfe1/library/Zend/Test/PHPUnit/ControllerTestCase.php#L937

that there is "$this->request->getControllerName()" return a empty string, you have to call dispatch, like in the zf1 docu.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/de/zend.test.phpunit.html

Hope this help you=)